# Is there a solution to set a linear gradient using one color

Tags: css, sass

On my project, users have the possibility to select an accent color for their profile page (var(--color-main)). Is there a possibility to create a gradient background using only that main color, for example by using the main color + a % applied to this color to make it darker (or lighter) and use this as second color to make the gradient. Is that possible?

```
.TabsHeader-module--wrapper--BMiDm .TabsHeader-module--bgBlock--qXkLH {
background-color: var(--color-main);
border-radius: 0 0 20rem 0;
height: 21.6rem;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: opacity is the simple solution, but not suitable necessarily if you need a solid color. Do you have a definition of what you mean by 'darken' or 'lighten'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that you can use variable colors with opacity control only if you give the value as RGB decimals, which are 3 numbers (e.g. 240, 240, 240). And later you can give it a 4th value, which will control the opacity of the color (i.e. will make it darker or lighter).
Here is an example:

```
:root {
 --color: 190,190,190;
}

div {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(var(--color), 0.8), rgba(var(--color), 0.3));
}
```

Thanks to [Thankful Teira](https://www.codegrepper.com/profile/thankful-teira-p1hq2y5zkhk7) from codegrepper.com

Answer (score 2):

This is an example with two custom properties defined:

- `--color` is your main color
- `--alpha` is the opacity quota (0-1) applied to `--color` for having the second gradient color

The `background-image` style attribute is set using a gradient shading from `--color` to `--color(alpha)`

That was made possible with `rgba` to define colors [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/rgba)

```css
:root {
  --color: 240, 0, 0;
  --alpha: .5;
}

.gradient{

  background-image:
    linear-gradient(
      to right,
      rgba(var(--color), 1),
      rgba(var(--color), var(--alpha))
    );

  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```